# Sum of indicator infinite expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X_n = \sum_j^n I_j$ be a sum of possibly dependent, but identically distibuted indicator random variables. 
        If $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n] \rightarrow \infty$, then 
        $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n > 0) \rightarrow 1$.

I am looking for if this is true, and if so, a hopefully simple proof.

$\mathbb{P}(X_n > 0) = 1- \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) \geq 1-\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{P}(\{I_j=0\}) = 1-n\mathbb{P}(\{I_1=0\}) = 1-n(1-\mathbb{P}(\{I_j=1\})$, but I can't continue from here, even if the proof is true.

Comment: Hint: $E[I_j]=E[I_k]$ for all $j,kl$ and $E[X_n]=\sum_{j=1}^{n} E[I_j]=nE[I_1]$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, I've gotten that, but I cannot show that $nP(I_1 = 1) \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $nP(I_1 = 0) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: What if each $I_j$ is exactly the same. Then $E[X_n]=nP(I_1=1)\to\infty$ except in the case when $P(I_1=1)=0.$ But $P(X_n>0)=P(I_1=1)$ for all $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it could be the case that $P(I_1 = 1) = \sqrt{n}$, and the probabilities are not linear, so in order to show that $P(X_n > 0)$, I think that one must show that $P(X_n = 0) \rightarrow 0$, which I can't show if they are dependent, which is why I am not inclined to believe it is true.

Comment: Umm, you said the $I_j$ are identically distributed. And $P(I_j=1)$ is a probability, so it can't be bigger than $1.$